# How can I write HTTP Request Body to a file in a Java Web App?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, io

This is the code I have:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final ServletInputStream inputStream = req.getInputStream();
    int read;
    File file = new File("koray.txt");
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(read);
    }
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

When I get a HTTP Request like this:

```
beer-characteristics=ğ
```

in koray.txt I will see:

```
beer-characteristics=%C4%9F
```

Well c49f seems to be the utf-8 hex value for 'ğ' but why am I seeing the hex value in the file, but not the 'ğ' itself?

Edit: This does not work either:

```
final OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
    outputStreamWriter.write(read);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input stream with:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Then read data from buffered reader in utf-8.

Comment: Thanks, but the result will be the same.